# How to remove horizontal lines on a text table in Tableau online?

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a text table in a worksheet in Tableau online. There are horizontal rules in the text table that I want to remove. There does not seem to be a way to get rid of them though. If anyone has a suggestion it would be appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Format - Borders - Row Divider. Set the Header and Pane to None, and these lines will vanish.

[image]

Comment: In Tableau Online, where do I access `Format Borders`? I am not seeing that option.

Comment: Are you editing within Tableau Online, or using Tableau Desktop?

Comment: I am using Tableau Online.

Comment: Ok, perhaps it's not possible. This is what you can do in Tableau Online: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/server_desktop_web_edit_differences.htm#formatting

Comment: I suggest you do your editing in Tableau Desktop; it's easier to use and offers more power to you as a developer.